# Anaconda3 Installation - no error during installation, but anaconda prompt and navigator menus don't appear. And _conda.exe

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda 3 on windows 7 (64bits).

During the installation there are no error messages. It seems allright. However, I don't get Anaconda Prompt and Navigator.
I already tried playing with environment variables and uninstall /reinstall couple of times. Nothing works!

I noticed that in the folder Anaconda3 there is a file _conda.exe. I also noticed there are no Scripts folder under Anaconda3.
Despite the fact the installation reported no errors I think there is something wrong in the installation. When I type de command conda info I get:

'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I've tried several different `Anaconda3-xxxx.xx-Windows-x86_64.exe` on https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/ from 2019 to 2020 and finally I found Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe works for me.

Comment: I also got '_conda.exe' instead of 'conda.exe'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the underscore?

`_conda.exe install -c conda-forge prompt`

Comment: I get the following error NoBaseEnvironmentError: This conda installation has no default base environment. Use 'conda create' to create new environments and 'conda activate' to activate environments.